# Por que existe uma tag linux? O que isso tem a ver com programacao?

Tags: debate

Por que existe uma tag linux? As tags nao deveriam ser relacionadas apenas a programacao?

Comment: Você pelo menos se deu ao trabalho de ler a descrição da tag?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info Boa leitura.

Answer (score 10):

Linux não deve **apenas** ser chamado de um sistema operacional, e sim uma plataforma em si, como desenvolvimento para Android, GNU, etc...

A tag também é referida à API Unix no geral, o qual tem contexto na programação.

Além disso, como descrito na [descrição da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info), ela é utilizada para situações de categoria

- Programação com as APIs fornecidas pelo sistema operacional
- A implementação do kernel
- Ferramentas de programação e técnicas de uso no sistema GNU/Linux.

E não como:

- Dúvidas sobre a utilização de um desktop ou laptop do sistema GNU/Linux
- Perguntas sobre administração de sistemas GNU/Linux para outros usuários e sistemas GNU/Linux em rede em um contexto mais complicado, ou uma rede doméstica mínima.

Algumas perguntas são essencialmente feitas para a tag <kbd>Unix</kbd>, mas algumas características presentes em Unix não são encontrados nos sistemas operacionais que executam o mesmo como mencionado anteriormente.